# Missing class: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons-config

I am following [an online example](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Special_Characters_and_Escaping) to read information from a basic properties file. As I started to implement the code I keep getting the following error at the top of the class.

> `The type org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

I have sought to resolve the error by downloading the apache commons lang package from [this page](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and including it in my project properties, but this did not resolve the issue.

Can someone please give me some insight on why this error is being thrown, and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NestableException` class was available in commons-lang v2.6 but it is not included in the latest version (see [Javadocs for v3.1](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/)).

The [Maven dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.9) for commons-configuration v1.9 show that it depends upon commons-lang 2.6.

So I suspect you downloaded the latest version of commons-lang by mistake?

Comment: This is the case, I went into the archive and got 2.6 and everything works as intended.